# (Nivo Slider) Grab title from Image and add to Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I'm trying to grab the title from the current slide (image) and then add the title data to a div. [Here nivo slider's demo.](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/)

I've tried to use the afterChange function within Nivo slider but without any luck.

```
afterChange: function(){
   $('#status .caption').data('nivo:vars').currentSlide.attr('title');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done it. Hope this helps someone.

```
  current_title = jQuery('#slider').data('nivo:vars').currentImage.attr('title');
  jQuery('#slider .caption').text(current_title);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it fail if you had a title like title="#imgCaption" where the nivo slider would have to load the content of #imgCaption to display as a caption?
I don't know for sure.. but to make sure, I'll post an answer below

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use something like this: I haven't done anything with Nivo and I'm not sure '.data('nivo:vars').currentSlide.attr('title')' actually exists...

```
afterChange: function() {
    var title = $('#slider').data('nivo:vars').currentSlide.attr('title');
    $('#status .caption').html(title);
}
```

Comment: TypeError: $(...).data(...).currentSlide.attr is not a function

Comment: $('#slider').data("nivo:vars").currentImage. exists inside Nivo to capture the data of the current slide.

Comment: I just test it out. $('#slider').data("nivo:vars").currentImage exsists and can be used from outside the slider.

so getting the title like this:
var title = $('#slider').data("nivo:vars").currentImage.attr('title');
will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sliderSelector = '#slider'; // Replace with your slider selector
var index = 0; // You start with slide 0 as the first slide

controlNav: true, // This solution relies on this to work
$(sliderSelector).nivoSlider({
    afterChange: function() {
        index = $(sliderSelector + ' .nivo-controlNav .nivo-control').filter('.active').index();
        showCaption(sliderSelector, index);
    },
    afterLoad: function() {
        showCaption(sliderSelector, index);
    }
});
```

And the showCaption function

```
function showCaption(sliderSelector, index) {
    var title = $($(sliderSelector + ' img').get(index)).prop('title');
    if (title.length > 0) { // Determines if it has to show a caption
        var caption = $(sliderSelector + ' .nivo-caption').html(); // Gets the current caption
        console.log(caption);
    }
}
```